# Where is the ancient preprocessor?

Tags: history, c

I found the [old C compiler from V6](https://github.com/bbarker/AncientenUnixen/tree/main/v6/c), and, though it seems to the modern eye a little different from good, idiomatic C, evidently it uses things like `#include` and `#define`, but I do not see how it implements these.

Was this an external program at that time? In that case, is it lost to obscurity or am I missing something in this codebase?

Comment: Not sure, but wasn't _cpp_, the preprocessor an external tool anyway?

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, but nowadays (clang/gcc) the external `cpp` tool is only provided for compatibility and you should invoke cc -E on those compilers instead, otherwise some expansions might not succeed properly.

Comment: my eyes! it seems to perform complete manual parsing. Must have been horrible to write. BTW which compiler was used to compile this C compiler for first pass???

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It was made in incremental steps from a B compiler actually. I'm pretty sure there's a question on this site about that

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In V6, the C preprocessor is part of `cc`, the compiler driver; see [the `expand()` function](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6/usr/source/s1/cc.c#L235) in `cc.c`. The directory you linked to contains the source code to the two passes of the C compiler, `c0` and `c1` (and their floating-point variants, `fc0` and `fc1`), and the optional optimiser, `c2`. The passes are driven by `cc`, whose source code is available in the `s1` directory.

As far as I can tell, the external preprocessor [was introduced in V7](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/cmd/cpp/README).

In both cases, the preprocessor can be invoked using `cc -P`. The [V6](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/cc) and [V7](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-7th/1/cc) `cc(1)` manpages provide more detail. Dennis M. Ritchie’s [*The Development of the C Language*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) paper gives this context:

> Many other changes occurred around 1972-3, but the most important was the introduction of the preprocessor, partly at [the urging of Alan Snyder](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA010218), but also in recognition of the utility of the the file-inclusion mechanisms available in BCPL and PL/I. Its original version was exceedingly simple, and provided only included files and simple string replacements: `#include` and `#define` of parameterless macros. Soon thereafter, it was extended, mostly by Mike Lesk and then by John Reiser, to incorporate macros with arguments and conditional compilation. The preprocessor was originally considered an optional adjunct to the language itself. Indeed, for some years, it was not even invoked unless the source program contained a special signal at its beginning. This attitude persisted, and explains both the incomplete integration of the syntax of the preprocessor with the rest of the language and the imprecision of its description in early reference manuals.

The “special signal at its beginning” is `#` as the very first character; this test can be seen [in V5’s `cc.c`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V5/usr/source/s1/cc.c#L239) (and in V6’s).

(I’m linking to Diomidis Spinellis’ Unix history repo because I’m familiar with it, but [the repo you’ve found also has `cc` in `s1`](https://github.com/bbarker/AncientenUnixen/tree/main/v6/s1).)

Comment: It was internal, then external, and nowadays internal again?

Comment: Internal, then external, then it depends :-). GCC still has an external `cpp` but it’s not used when compiling.

Comment: (Once `cpp` became available, other tools started using it; `xmkmf` in particular needs a working `cpp`.)

Comment: Did it really start internal though? Everything about Unix and the preprocessor specs suggests it was conceived as an external tool.

Comment: There is no `cc.c` file in the cited source. And the comments in `c0.c`et al hint at each one being a separate program.

Comment: Given that C evolved at around the same time as the invention of pipes, I am not surprised that an early version of C would have an internal preprocessor.

Comment: @vonbrand `cc.c` is part of the same V6 source, even though it’s not in the same directory; it drives `c0`, `c1`, and `c2` (look for `char *pass` in `cc.c`). Look at the `run` file in the same directory as `c0.c` to see how the passes are constructed.

Comment: The history I always learned was that, early on, the preprocessor was a separate program, and was only executed  if the driver script saw a '#' as the very first byte of the source file.  But what version that applied to, I can no longer say. By the time I wrote C, the preprocessor always ran (though it might still have been separate).

Comment: @another-dave the `#` test is visible in `cc.c` as far back as [V5](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V5/usr/source/s1/cc.c#L239) at least, but it is part of `cc` there (and in V6).

Comment: @another-dave I think the argument boils down to this: It is external if you view `cc` as a "driver" that is separate from the actual compilation process, which in the early days consisted of passes run as different programs. It is internal if you consider "the C compiler" to include `cc`.

Comment: @texdr.aft from the user’s perspective though the C compiler was `cc`; I don’t think the separate passes were run directly by users (or at least, by most users).

Comment: @StephenKitt Right. I suppose my point was that `cc` and the compiler proper were not the same executable.

Comment: @texdr.aft yup, I get that ;-).

Comment: The ability to combine multiple source files in a compilation unit would seem to have obvious value, and I find it curious that it would have required using an external program to produce a file with all of the inputs concatenated.  I wonder if there would have been any problem with saying that if e.g. a command-line argument starts with a +, the compiler will process treat the remainder of that argument as a source file name, but when it reaches the end of that file it will open the file specified by the next command-line argument and treat it as a continuation of the same compilation unit?

Comment: I find it very strange that `c0`, `c1` and `c2` are in a completely different directory from the actual compiler executable thing itself. That kind of shenanigan would not get past code review today would it?

Comment: @OmarL: Unless I'm confused about what you're talking about, the idea is they're not in your PATH as they're not user-invokable in any normal sense.

Comment: @Joshua I mean, the source code is in a completely different directory